# Chrome Extension to trigger click event on icon press

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I'm trying to make an extension for Chrome, so that when the icon is clicked, it triggers a click event on a div in the relevant webpages. I can't figure it out. Can anyone see or tell me what I'm doing wrong? Is this even possible?

Manifest.json

```
{
        "name": "Name",
        "version": "1.0",
        "manifest_version": 2,

    "icons": {
     "128": "icon128.png",
     "48": "icon.png"
   },
        "browser_action": {
        "name": "Name"
        },
        "background":{
            "scripts":["background.js"]
        },
        "permissions":["https://inbox.google.com/*"] //Put All your URL here
 }
```

background

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    if (tab.url.indexOf("https://inbox.google.com/*") != -1) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
            "file": "clicky.js"
        }, function () {
            console.log("Script Executed .. ");
        });
    }
});
```

js

```
$('.b2')[0].click()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not including jquery in your `manifest.json` and you don't have access to the page's jQuery instance ([read this](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment)), so you can't use jQuery on your content scripts.

Assuming there's an element with the 'b2' class present, change the code in `clicky.js` to this and it should work:

```
var btn = document.querySelector('.b2');

if(btn){
   btn.click();
}
```

**EDIT**

Also, in your `background.js`, remove the wildcard when you call `indexOf`:

```
if (tab.url.indexOf("https://inbox.google.com/") != -1) {
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a stupid oversight. However, it still doesn't work even without the JQuery. I'm stumped.

Comment: Nope. Nothing. The icon loads, so it's definitely there. And .b2 most certainly exists.

Comment: @TomOdlin I just compiled an extension with the changes mentioned aboove, installed Inbox, opened https://inbox.google.com/, clicked and...it worked, redirected me to "Nothing in Pinned". So what is not working on your end? Are you getting errors in the tab/extension console?

Comment: I had forgotten to save the new javascript. It works now. Thanks!